# Difference between consistency and law of noncontradiction

Tags: logic, foundations

The law of noncontradition states that (in a system $S$), for any proposition $p$, $\neg p$ and $p$ cannot be both true at the same time. Does it mean that $\neg p$ and $p$ cannot both be implied in $S$?

So does the validity of the law of noncontradiction imply consistency of $S$?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're talking about? It's not entirely clear what you mean by "$\neg p$ and $p$ cannot both be implied in $S$"

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Choose a proposition $p$ that can be formulated in the system $S$, suppose that from the axioms of $S$ I can repeatedly apply the rules of inference to obtain both $p$ and $\neg p$. Is this possible, if the law of noncontradiction holds? I think I have some misunderstanding about the difference between $p$ is true and $p$ follows from the axioms of $S$.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy I think I'd solve my problem if I knew what does it mean for  a proposition to be true

Answer (score 2):

Consistency is a property of a formal system $S$ ... and it is a *syntactical*property: it indeed says that $p$ and $\neg p$ cannot both be derived in system $S$

The Law of Non-Contradiction is something that is assumed to hold true for most logics. It is a *semantical* property in the sense that it is assumed that statements cannot be both true and false at the same time.

To see the difference, take classical propositional logic. In classical propositional logic we assume the Law of Non-contradiction. OK, but now we can try and define a formal system $S$ with axioms, rules, etc. And suppose that this system contains the rule:

**Hokus Ponens**

$\therefore \varphi$

(that is, from nothing, you can infer anything you want)

Now, clearly such a system $S$ is not consistent, since we can infer both $\varphi$ and $\neg \varphi$.  And, as such, this sytem is not a good axiomatiation of classical propositional logic.

Comment: I'm sorry for the question, but what does it mean to be true for a proposition in the system $S$? How do you define truth?

Answer (score 0):

If the system $S$ is consistent, then it will not be possible to validly deduce the statements $p$ and $\neg p$ from the axioms using the rules of inference. If the system is inconsistent, then it will be possible to deduce such a contradiction from the axioms. In that event, we would be assured that at least one of the axioms of $S$ is false. Note that system $S$ I'm referring to is a classical system.

Comment: Can a system be inconsistent if the law of noncontradiction holds for this system?

Comment: If it's possible to derive a contradiction from the axioms of system $S$, then the law of noncontradiction would not hold for $S$. However, if it is not possible to derive such a contradiction from the axioms of $S$, then the law of noncontradiction would hold for $S$. The law of noncontradiction is a property that any given logical system has or does not have. Most logical systems do have this property. I assumed that you were speaking of a classical propositional system in your question. This is what is generally taught in beginning logic, and such a system does have this property.

Comment: So the law of noncontradiction is the same as consistency?